# Tableau Dynamic Filter

Tags: tableau-api

[Dashboard in Progress]
I am working on a status dashboard to track the progress of several projects. When a filter is applied to a field, I would like the menu of items for the other filters only to contain the relevant options. I have tried adding filters to context, and selecting "only relevant values" in the filter menu, but it does not work.

Comment: Setting the filters to only relevant values should work. Does this filter setting make no difference?

Comment: Only relevant values does not work.

Comment: Are you blending data and your filters are coming from the secondary data source?

Comment: Data is all from a single worksheet.

Comment: Ok, so doesn't make sense. Can you provide some sample data and screenshots of your Tableau workbook incl the filters section? Please indicate which filters aren't showing only relative values.

Comment: Where can I share that information with you?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: @AndyTARSols, how can I share example data and my dahsboard? nekomusume, i don't know how to access the code

Comment: You can paste screenshots into your question and also paste sample data there as well - a few records in a table should suffice

Comment: RecordID Client Coverage Date EGA Name1 Line of Business Pod Sample Number Status Subsector Test Type Role Assignee Completed - Person Completed - Sample Incomplete - Sample Status Date
1 AAA 6/30/2019 A Trad B 1 Complete Ins A Preparer Dennis Rodman 0 0 1 05/18/2020
1 AAA 6/30/2019 A Trad B 1 Complete Ins A Reviewer 1 Scottie Pips 0 0 0 05/18/2020
1 AAA 6/30/2019 A Trad B 1 Complete Ins A Reviewer 2 Mike Jordan 0 0 0 05/18/2020
1 AAA 6/30/2019 A Trad B 1 Complete Ins A Reviewer 3 Joe Blow 0 0 0 05/18/2020
@AndyTARSols

Comment: You can get a free account at http://public.tableau.com and publish your workbook there, and then publish a link the workbook in your question. That will make it much easier for people to help you. Also if you are going to show data here, it would be easier for others to make use of if you showed it in your question instead of a comment. Otherwise, people have to reformat it by hand. Not criticizing, but trying to increase chances of you getting answers. Welcome to SO

Comment: For some reason, it only works if you select "Only relevant values" from the filter card on the right. But now it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it only works if you select "Only relevant values" from the filter card on the right. But now it works. Thanks for the help